# 'mongorestore' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, mongodb

I tried this way but it still does not work.

Control Panel >> System and Security >> System >> Advanced System Settings >> Advanced >> Environment variables.

Add MongoDB's bin folder path to path variable in Environment variables

Error message:

'mongorestore' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Did you install the tool? In latest release 4.4 these tools are not part of the basic package anymore and have to be installed separately. See https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools or use direct link: https://fastdl.mongodb.org/tools/db/mongodb-database-tools-windows-x86_64-100.1.1.zip

Answer (score 3):

If you guys using version above 4.2 its doesn't have mongostore in your bin folder, so install one more tool i.e https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools
after installing this add it's bin path to your env
ex: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Tools\100\bin
or make your root path same in cmd ex: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Tools\100\bin
then run the command mongorestore /dump. Here /dump is path for your dump folder.

Comment: Perfect!! This should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: I opened CMD in the exact path(In my path was ```C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\mongodb-database-tools-windows-x86_64-100.9.0\mongodb-database-tools-windows-x86_64-100.9.0\bin```) then got the same error. Then I tried to run CMD as run as administrator. then works.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your using the msi version not the rpm or tgz if your using windows. Also, add the directory of the files you want to restore to your path. The mongorestore command was not being recognized there until I added it, it was only being recognized in the directory I had it installed.