# command prompt are showing 'mongorestore' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: database, windows, mongodb

I have installed the MongoDB community version in my window machine and set the environment path of the MongoDB bin folder. From the command prompt, mongod and mongo command is working but mongorestore and mongodump are not working. [image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63794153/mongorestore-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-pr

Comment: Thanks this is working now

Comment: This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/67500724/14426381

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to install separately. Please take reference of below link

https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools

Comment: I downloaded database-tools, but there is only one executable in the archive, named "mongosh.exe"

Comment: I have downloaded the ZIP file that does not contain "mongorestore", Then I downloaded the MSI version that contains the restore tool

Answer (score 18):

Yes as @Rohit said , we need to download separately from the given link . But that is not enough to run the `mongorestore`  command .

Additionally we should set the path of the Mongo db tools in to our environment variable. After I have done that the command has recognized from my end .

Sample path set in to my  windows machine environment varible
eg,

```
C:\Users\ssa\Downloads\mongodb-database-tools-windows-x86_64-100.2.1\bin
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also download the mongodb database tools and paste it's contents of the bin folder to the bin folder of mongodb server.
It works for me in mongodb version 4.4:

Example:-
From:
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Tools\100\bin 
to:
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me! I'm using windows.

1. Download the `zip` file from `https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools`
2. Move the `exe` files in the `bin` folder into `"C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/5.0/bin"`
3. Go to "start" on your computer
4. Search for "edit the system environment variables"
5. Click on "Environment Variables..."
6. In the second list, double-click on "path"
7. Add new path `"C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/5.0/bin"`
8. Restart your computer (this was essential for me)
9. Go to your command line
10. Type `mongorestore --version`

Answer (score 2):

In new versions of mongodb, tools are separately installed so do install mongodb tools from https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools
create a separate folder `tools` in `programfile/mongoDB/tool` then extract downloaded tools there, then go to

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\tool\mongodb-database-tools-windows-x86_64-100.5.1\bin
```

and create an environment variable of that path, then you will me able to use mongodump mongorestore

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:** Download MongoDB Command Line Database Tools (msi)
from https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools 
**Step 2:** Copy your tools path i.e C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Tools\100 
**Step 3:** In your environment variables setup a new path for C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Tools\100

Restart your server and you are good to go